# Fetched 0 records in Robo3T

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I've imported my files in Robo3T used simple db.getCollection and it found the collection. When I used a simple where statement I got the message: "Fetched 0 records". I tried with the simplest commands and all returned the same. I checked manually and all data is in the db. What is going on?

Comment: Share your query.

Comment: make sure you have used the right database.

Comment: It seems that the command didn't find the database.

Answer (score 0):

You may be connected to a "test" database.
try to run the command `use 'your db name'` to switch to it then re-try running your commands.

Also, you can check if your collection is present or not via the command `show collections`.